# How can I use the Perl debugger's *supported* editor?

Tags: linux, perl, debugging

The Perl debugger always says: "Editor support available". I believe every one can see this, *but* how can I use it?

```
my-computer$ perl -de2

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.33
Editor support available.

Enter h or `h h' for help, or `man perldebug' for more help.

main::(-e:1):   2
  DB<1>
```

By the way, I got the above prompt on a Linux/[Ubuntu 11.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_11.04_.28Natty_Narwhal.29) (Natty Narwhal) machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The message is a little confusing. It's telling you it can support *running inside an editor*, not that there is a special Perl debugger editor.

The Perl debugger can detect if it's talking to a terminal or if it's running inside an editor.  This controls a number of things, the biggest is whether the debugger prints anything or leaves it up to the editor to handle the display.  If you're really curious, look through [the debugger code](https://github.com/mirrors/perl/blob/blead/lib/perl5db.pl) for `$slave_editor`.

Why does it feel the need to inform the user of this? I did a little digging and the debugger [used to only support Emacs debugging](https://github.com/mirrors/perl/commit/055fd3a9). It's a bit more useful to inform the user "Emacs support available" than that *some* editor *somewhere* will work with the debugger. The Emacs message came in [with the first version of the debugger sprung fully formed from the head of Ilya](https://github.com/mirrors/perl/commit/d338d6fe1dfdfdbc07c2d6d7a2a4ae7db5887d93).

The Perl debugger is also really three entities.  The perl5db.pl script, the [DB API](https://metacpan.org/module/DB), and the debugging hooks in the language itself which those two use.  An editor may use perl5db.pl, or it may talk directly using DB.

There are a few editors which can hook into the Perl debugger. One is Emacs which you can start by opening a Perl program in Emacs and using `M-x perldb`. [Komodo](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide) and [Padre](http://padre.perlide.org/trac/wiki/Features/Perl5Debugger) also have debugger support.

Comment: There's also vim support in VimDebug project: https://github.com/kablamo/VimDebug

Comment: Re *"Emacs which you can start by opening a Perl program"*: Don't you mean opening a Perl program from within Emacs?